# extracting rows from a file that match with the second file and merge them as single file

Tags: text-processing, awk, cat

I have a file contains some positions,

```
head positions
142541687
142541814
142541910
142542976
142544533
142546366
142548674
142560386
```

I have another folder contains of 1800 files, each file belongs to one individual (1800 individuals in total). Column 2 is position and column 4 is individual ID:

```
 head NA20507.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.TSI.low_coverage.20130415.bam_dp
1   142541687   78 NA20507
1   142535975   79 NA20507
1   142535976   79 NA20507
1   142535977   77 NA20507
1   142535978   78 NA20507
1   142535979   77 NA20507
```

or example of another individual,

```
head NA20901.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GIH.low_coverage.20120522.bam_dp
1   142541687   135 NA20901
1   142535975   135 NA20901
1   142535976   137 NA20901
1   142535977   138 NA20901
1   142535978   138 NA20901
1   142535979   136 NA20901
1   142535980   135 NA20901
```

For each individual file, I want to keep only those rows that have the positions from the position file (second column of individual file matches the position file), however I want to store it for each position separately!

```
   cat NA20507.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.TSI.low_coverage.20130415.bam_dp_match142541687
        1   142541687   78 NA20507
```

In the end I want to combine these files for all individuals:
This is for example for position 142541687

```
head desired_pos142541687
1   142541687   78  NA20507
1   142541687   135 NA20901
```

or for the position 142542976;

```
desired_pos142542976

    1   142535976   79 NA20507
    1   142535976   137 NA20901
```

Comment: Do you actually _need_ the intermediate `.bam_dp_match142541687` file?

Comment: @ Kusalananda, no I do not, just wanted to show for better understanding.

Comment: @ steeldriver, yes. just edited slightly It is there now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more or less the same sort of answer as some that you've already had for similar questions:  Read one file first (the positions), then parse the other files and extract the data.

```
awk 'NR == FNR { pos[$1]=1; next } $2 in pos { f="desired_pos" $2; print >>f; close(f) }' positions NA*.bam_dp
```

If given the two individual files in the question, and if `positions` included 142535975, then this would create `desired_pos142535975` with the following contents:

```
1   142535975   79 NA20507
1   142535975   135 NA20901
```

This would work assuming that all the positions referred to chromosome 1 (or at least the *same* chromosome as in the individual files), since there is no chromosome name information other than the location in the `positions` file.

Comment: I am actually getting a syntax error. I have 340 positions, and I need to make the "desired_pos" output for each of these positions in the position file that match the position in the individual file.

Comment: @Anna1364 What is the error you're getting?

Comment: awk: cmd. line:1: NR == FNR { pos[$1]=1; next } $2 in pos { f="desired_pos" $2; print >>f; close f }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                ^ syntax error

Comment: @Anna1364 Ah, I see now. You are using GNU `awk` and I'm not. I will fix this. Just a moment...

Comment: @Anna1364 Fixed. `close f` needed to be changed to be `close(f)`.